# Find the coefficient of $ x^6 $in the given expansion.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^6$ in $\left[(1+x)(1+x^2)^2(1+x^3)^3 \cdots (1+x^n)^n\right]$.

---

**Expansion**
$$\left[\left(1+\binom11x \right)\left(1+\binom21x + \binom22x^2 \right)\left(1 +\binom31x+\binom32x^2+\binom33x^3 \right)\cdots \left(1 + \binom n1 x + \binom n2x^2 + \cdots +\binom n nx^n \right) \right]$$

I expanded it as shown above but couldn't proceed further. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken mod $x^7$ (meaning we drop anything with a power of $x$ greater than $6$), we have

$$(1+x)(1+x^2)^2(1+x^3)^3\cdots\equiv(1+x)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+3x^3+3x^6)(1+4x^4)(1+5x^5)(1+6x^6)\\
\equiv(1+x+5x^5+5x^6)(1+2x^2+5x^4+8x^6)(1+3x^3+9x^6)\\
$$

where in the second step we've paired $(1+x)$ with $1+5x^5$, $(1+2x^2+x^4)$ with $(1+4x^4)$, and $(1+3x^3+3x^6)$ with $(1+x^6)$. The coefficient of $x^6$ in the resulting expansion is

$$5+8+9+1\cdot2\cdot3=28$$

(where the $1\cdot2\cdot3$ comes from the product $x\cdot2x^2\cdot3x^3$).

Answer (score 1):

Here we give a supplement regarding the cases $1\leq n\leq 5$. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

> We obtain
>
> **Cases $n=1,2$:** 
>   \begin{align*}
>   [x^6](1+x)=[x^6](1+x)(1+x^2)^2\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case $n=3$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{[x^6]}&\color{blue}{(1+x^3)^3(1+x^2)^2(1+x)}\\
>   &=[x^6](1+3x^3+3x^6)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\tag{1}\\
>   &=\left([x^6]+3[x^3]+3[x^0]\right)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\tag{2}\\
>   &=0+3\cdot2+3\cdot 1\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=9}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case $n=4$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{[x^6]}&\color{blue}{(1+x^4)^4(1+x^3)^3(1+x^2)^2(1+x)}\\
>   &=[x^6](1+4x^4)(1+3x^3+3x^6)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\\
>   &=[x^6](1+3x^3+4x^4+3x^6)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\tag{3}\\
>   &=\left([x^6]+3[x^3]+4[x^2]+3[x^0]\right)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\\
>   &=0 + 3\cdot 2+4\cdot 2+3\cdot 1\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=17}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case $n=5$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{[x^6]}&\color{blue}{(1+x^5)^5(1+x^4)^4(1+x^3)^3(1+x^2)^2(1+x)}\\
>   &=[x^6](1+5x^5)(1+4x^4)(1+3x^3+3x^6)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+x)\\
>   &=[x^6](1+4x^4+5x^5)(1+2x^2+3x^3+x^4+6x^5+3x^6)(1+x)\tag{4}\\
>   &=\left([x^6]+4[x^2]+5[x]\right)(1+2x^2+3x^3+x^4+6x^5+3x^6)(1+x)\\
>   &=(6+3)+4\cdot 2+5\cdot 1\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=22}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the terms skipping summands with powers of $x$ greater than $6$.
- In (2) we use the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we multiply out the left-most two terms ignoring summands which do not contribute to $[x^6]$.
- In (4) we multiply out the left-most two terms and the next two terms ignoring summands which do not contribute to $[x^6]$.